Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected url to equal url in Cypress
Trying log in after 2fa , is not possible log in with Cypress, it gives the following error Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected url to equal url.
How can I handle this issue?
it("Login", () => {
    cy.visit("/login");

    cy.get("[name=email]").type("example@com"); 
    cy.get("[name=password]").type("example!");
    cy.get("button[type=submit]").click();

    cy.location("pathname").should("equal", "/two-fa");

    // Enter two-factor authentication code
    cy.get('.code_digits.d-flex [type=number]').each(($el, index, $list) => {
      cy.wrap($el).type(index + 1);
    });

    cy.wait(5000); //
    cy.url().should("eq", "/"); 
  }); 
});

